# Write values of a dictionary one in each line with DictWriter

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, bioinformatics

So I have a Python dictionary with protein sequences and their ids. I wanted to convert that dictionary to a CSV file to upload it as a dataset to fine-tune a transformer. However, when I create the CSV it appears with the dictionary shape (key-value, key-value...).

What I want is the CSV to have one key and in the next line it's value, and that shape consecutively. Is there a way to add a \n or something like that to have it's key and value in one line?

Shape of the dictionary:

```
{'NavAb:/1126': 'TNIVESSFFTKFIIYLIVLNGITMGLETSKTFMQSFGVYTTLFNQIVITIFTIEIILRIYVHRISFFKDPWSLFDFFVVAISLVPTSSGFEILRVLRVLRLFRLVTAVPQMRKI', 'Shaker:/1656': 'SSQAARVVAIISVFVILLSIVIFCLETLEDEVPDITDPFFLIETLCIIWFTFELTVRFLACPLNFCRDVMNVIDIIAIIPYFITTLNLLRVIRLVRVFRIFKLSRHSKGLQIL', .....
```

What I want in the CSV:

```
protein id
protein sequence
protein id
protein sequence
.....
```

The code I have for the moment:

```
def parse_file(input_file):
  parsed_seqs = {}
  curr_seq_id = None
  curr_seq = []
  for line in newfile:
     line = line.strip()
     line = line.replace('-', '')
     if line.startswith(">"):
        if curr_seq_id is not None:
          parsed_seqs[curr_seq_id] = ''.join(curr_seq)
        curr_seq_id = line[1:]
        curr_seq = []
        continue

    curr_seq.append(line)
 parsed_seqs[curr_seq_id] = ''.join(curr_seq)
 return parsed_seqs

newfile = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/seqs.fasta")
parsed_seqs = parse_file(newfile)

with open('sequences.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
w = csv.DictWriter(f, parsed_seqs.keys())
w.writeheader()
w.writerow(parsed_seqs)
```

The shape I want:

[image]

New shape:
[image]

Comment: Your desired format does not seem to actually be a comma separated value file. Can you give the output you would expect from your example dictionary?

Comment: The dictionary currently writes itself one id and sequence for each column in the CSV file. I wanted to have everything in two columns, but I don't know if that is possible to write directly from a dictionary. I also edited the post above, thanks @ogdenkev

Comment: Do you mean you want this output?` `Protein ID,Protein Sequence\nNavAB/1126,TNIVESS...`

Comment: Yes, that's right! I have also updated the post @ogdenkev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get CSV output with 2 columns, one for Protein ID and one for Protein Sequence, you can do this.

```py
parsed_seqs = {
  'NavAb:/1126': 'TNIVESS',
  'Shaker:/1656': 'SSQAARVV'
}

column_names = ["Protein ID", "Protein Sequence"]

with open('sequences.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, column_names)
    w.writerow(column_names)
    w.writerows(parsed_seqs.items())
```

Output:

```
Protein ID,Protein Sequence
NavAb:/1126,TNIVESS
Shaker:/1656,SSQAARVV
```

As an aside, the `csv.DictWriter` class works well when you have a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is structured like `{"column1": "value1", "column2": "value2"}`. For example

```py
parsed_seqs = [
  {"ID": "NavAb", "Seq": "TINVESS"},
  {"ID": "Shaker", "Seq": "SSQAARVV"}
]
with open("sequences.fa", "wt", newline="") as fd:
  wrtr = csv.DictWriter(fd, ["ID", "Seq"])
  wrtr.writeheader()
  wrtr.writerows(parsed_seqs)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly, I have updated the post with a photo of what I want. I'm sorry.

Comment: My first block of code should give you that format, namely two columns. One labelled "Protein ID" and one labelled "Protein Sequence". Then one row for each of your parsed sequences. Did it not work for you?

Comment: No, not really, I still get them one after the other, you can see what I mean in the above post, I have put a new photo @ogdenkev

Comment: I managed to work it out, thank you for you help! @ogdenkev

Comment: Great! It looks like you were using `w.writerow(parsed_seqs.items())` instead of `writerows()`, with an `s`